# How can I use handlebars in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a `node.js` + `espress` + `handlebars` app that works fine on `localhost`. However, when I deploy it to Google Cloud Functions, my `public` directory, containing client-side javascript, css and jpg's etc., does not seem to be found or accessible.

When (in Chrome DevTools) I try to inspect the client code `.js` that is referenced in my handlebars main template, I get a message *Your client does not have permission to get URL /ClientCode.js from this server*.

What do I do wrong; anyone any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It sounds like you've made a traditional server that isn't suited to cloud functions, you're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: Is that really true? I am going a long way: my handlebars template is rendered alright, the only thing missing is the (loading of the) client code. For as far as I know, `let app = require('express')` yields a function that I can (and do) deploy to Google Functions.

Comment: You're better off using a managed node server in the cloud like Google App Engine (standard). Or did you mean that rather than cloud functions? Cloud functions typically query services (e.g. a database) and return data as JSON for modern Rest API endpoints (not traditional oldschool servers which serve HTML and other files). They don't serve static files afaik.

Comment: Not, I certainly meant Cloud Functions. But ... you pointed me to something obvious I overlooked: I just deploy the function (`app`), and not the rest of the supporting files. Maybe that is not possible, I have to sort that out. And I do implement REST api endpoints as well, but I was attempting to use the same software for route handlers for Express + Handlebars.